# Arithmetic sums with proof by induction

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, induction

Let $a,d, x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and this be the given arithmetic sequence:

$$a_{1} := a, \forall_{ n \in \mathbb{N}}: a_{n+1} := a_{n} + d$$

Now I am want to proof with induction that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$$ S_{n} := \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i} = \frac{n}{2}(a_{1} + a_{n}) = \frac{n}{2}(2a + (n - 1) d$$

To do this, I tried the following:

Base case: $ n = 1 , \sum_{i=1}^{1}a_{i} = a_{1} = \frac{1}{2} (a_{1} + a_{1}) = a = \frac{1}{2}(2a) + 0d = a $

Induction step: Suppose that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{1} = \frac{n}{2}(a_{1} + a_{n})= \frac{n}{2}(2a + (n - 1) d $$

still to proof: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_{i} = \frac{n+1}{2}(a_{1} + a_{n+1})= \frac{n+1}{2}(2a + ((n+1) - 1) d $$

Therefore: $$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i} + a_{n+1} \Leftrightarrow \frac{n}{2}(a_{1} + a_{n}) + a_{n+1} $$

I feel like I made a conceptual mistake in my approach, because now I don't know how to finish the induction. One reason being, that I don't know if I have to show $\frac{n+1}{2}(a_{i} + a_{n+1})$ or $ \frac{n+1}{2}(2a + ((n+1) - 1) d $ as a result of the proof.

Comment: I'm not sure that the first equality that you're trying to prove is quite right - shouldn't it be $\frac{n}{2}(a_1 + a_n)$?

Comment: You're completely right, my bad, that should have been $a_{1}$ instead of $a_{i}$

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_{i} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i} + a_{n+1}$$

Use the induction hypothesis at this stage to substitute $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}$ with $\frac{n}{2}(2a + (n - 1) d)$ to get:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}a_{i} = \frac{n}{2}(2a + (n - 1) d) + a_{n+1}$$

Now, use the expression for general term $a_n = a + (n-1)d$ to substitute $a_{n+1}$ in the above equation. Do the simplification to complete the proof.

Coming to the confusion which you express at the end, both the expressions are equivalent if we take the expression of $n^{th}$ term of an A.P. ($a_n = a + (n-1)d$) to be known.

Comment: Since the expressions are equivalent, can I write: 

$ \Leftrightarrow \frac{n}{2} (a_{1}+a_{n}) + a_{n+1} ?$ And then somehow transform the $a_{n+1}$ in a way, so $\frac{n}{2}$ becomes $\frac{n+1}{2}$ ?

Comment: Yes, you can do so. Although the final expression to arrive at is $\frac{n+1}{2} (a_{1}+a_{n+1})$. So I suspect you'll ultimately need to express in terms of $a$ and $d$.